# Change focus in wxpython list instead of selection with up/down keys

Tags: focus, wxpython, selection, listctrl

When i am navigating in a wxpython ListCtrl with the arrow keys the selection is directly changing along with the focus. But i only want to change the focus, not the selection. 
I tried to bind to the key down events and simply not skip it to the parent when it is a navigation key (key down/up, page down/up):

```
if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_DOWN:
    curr = self.GetFocusedItem()
    if not curr == self.GetItemCount()-1:
        self._set_focused_item(curr+1)
#...(other keys)
else:
    event.Skip()
```

But this way i would have to reimplement other stuff, too. For example, if the list is too big for the listctrl and gets scrollable the visible area will not scroll with the focus automatically.

So, is there a simpler way to achieve this? Tanks